# Does Azure ML have dplyr package of R preinstalled?

Tags: r, azure

Does Azure ML have the dplyr package installed? If not how to install dplyr package in Azure Ml studio. Kindly help.

Comment: the pipe operator belongs to `magrittr` package.

Comment: Even after enabling magrittr package I get an error saying unexpected symbol. I used the pipline operator %>% for filtering a level of a variable.

Comment: You need to explain what you do when you say "enable". Possible that you need to read R-FAQ section 7.30

Comment: By enable I mean I call the library of that package..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both packages should be preinstalled, and simply loading the packages with library("package-name") should do it.

Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt741980.aspx

When you load a package, do you get an error?